# Exporting contents of Visual Studio Designer view to an image

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, screenshot, designer

I'm designing a UI in WPF and want to be able to share the progress with a client. I could run the program and take a screenshot (Snipping Tool, etc.) or do the same with the results in the designer window. However, ideally I would like to avoid those manual steps (e.g. running the program, scaling the designer window to fit the entire UI, selecting the proper screen area to capture), because the designer has already rendered the UI for me. I'm wondering if there exists a more convenient way to export what is already rendered for me in the Visual Studio 2015 XAML designer window directly to a high quality image. I couldn't find (by looking through VS and search engines) an obvious way to do it, but perhaps someone knows of a way (or plugin/extension)?